# change UIButton image with array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, image, uibutton

novice need help! idea: when you press the button you need to change the image of the array. Yes, I'm stupid.

from **.h:*

```
{
    NSMutableArray *_cat;
    NSInteger _catindex;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *catbtn;

- (IBAction)catbutton:(id)sender;
```

from **.m:*`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _cat = [NSMutableArray array];

    UIImage *cat1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat1.png"];
    UIImage *cat2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat2.png"];
    UIImage *cat3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat3.png"];
    UIImage *cat4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat4.png"];
    UIImage *cat5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat5.png"];
    [_cat addObject:cat1];
    [_cat addObject:cat2];
    [_cat addObject:cat3];
    [_cat addObject:cat4];
    [_cat addObject:cat5];

    self.catbtn.image = [_cat objectAtIndex:_catindex];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)catbutton:(id)sender
{
    _catindex++;
    if (_catindex == _cat.count)
    {
        _catindex = 0;
    }
    self.catbtn.image = [_cat objectAtIndex:_catindex];

}
```

I do not know whether it is possible to do that, but I hope for your help.

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark top answer the answer that solved your question so others with the same issue know what solved it. If none of them solved your issue then leave a comment to ask further questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.catbtn.image = [_cat objectAtIndex:_catindex];
```

won't work, you need to use:

```
[self.catbtn setImage: [_cat objectAtIndex:_catindex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`forState` can be used to set the image for when the button is selected / highlight etc.

Answer (score 0):

use this to set image for UIButton

```
[self.catbtn setImage:[_cat objectAtIndex:_catindex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
self.catbtn.image = [_cat objectAtIndex:_catindex];
```

write this:

```
[self.catbtn setImage:[_cat objectAtIndex:_catindex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

in both places.